# How to disable Basic Auth on Neo4j 2.2.0-RC01

Tags: neo4j

Currently I use Neo4j 2.2.0-RC01. It has basic Auth enable as default. How can I disable the default Basic Auth on Neo4j 2.2.0-RC01?

Comment: see the manual: http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/security-server.html#security-server-auth

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In file `conf/neo4j-server.properties`, change the dbms.security.auth_enabled to false and restart Neo4j:

```
# Require (or disable the requirement of) auth to access Neo4j
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

Comment: sorry, but where do i find this file? i brew installed neo4j but could not find this file anywhere

Comment: The file `conf/neo4j-server.properties` should be located where homebrew unpacks the neo4j distro. This is usually (for all homebrew formulas) `/usr/local/Cellar`.

Comment: It's now neo4j.conf under /etc/neo4j ( or wherever you installed it)

Comment: Found it here: `/opt/neo4j-community-5.18.1/conf/neo4j.conf`

Answer (score 0):

For me that was only part of the problem. I had also installed neo4j onto my machine using **brew install** before I installed the gem.  When I was trying to start the server, it was trying to start the server from the brew installation, from inside the Cellar. I had edited the config, as described above, in the install in my project that I produced by following the neo4j install instructions. So it wasn't working.

Only when I brew uninstalled neo4j, and executed **./neo4j start_** from the bin folder, did it all work properly for me.