# Cannot start rails server with Neo4j db, response coed 401 instead of 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

Any clue how to fix this?

```
rails s -d
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
/Users/levi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.5/lib/neo4j-server/resource.rb:33:in `handle_response_error': Expected response code 200 Error for request http://localhost:7474/db/data/, 401, 401 (Neo4j::Server::Resource::ServerException)
    from /Users/levi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.5/lib/neo4j-server/resource.rb:37:in `expect_response_code'
```

Comment: you moved from postgres to Neo4j db ? :)

Comment: `HTTP 401` means unauthorized request. Perhaps you have to send the Authentication within your request? What version of Neo4J is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you installed Neo4j using the `rake install neo4j` task, make sure the server has started by pointing a web browser to `http://localhost:7474`. If it isn't running, you'll want to troubleshoot issues related to a server failing to start.

If you downloaded Neo4j 2.2.0 from neo4j.com or used brew within the last day or two, you'll need to go to that admin page once to change the password, then set it in the app, OR you can disable auth entirely as described at [How to disable Basic Auth on Neo4j 2.2.0-RC01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096616/how-to-disable-basic-auth-on-neo4j-2-2-0-rc01). I always disable auth in Neo4j 2.2.0 in my test and dev environments.

Comment: the browser works with this address http://localhost:7474. The db server is up and running. Here is the proof: rake neo4j:info
Info from Neo4j development...
Neo4j Server is running at pid 631
Using Java version: CurrentJDK
NEO4J_HOME:        /Users/levi/rails_projects/woka-neo/db/neo4j/development
NEO4J_SERVER_PORT: 7474
NEO4J_INSTANCE:    /Users/levi/rails_projects/woka-neo/db/neo4j/development
JAVA_HOME:         /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: where is the file? i have been trying to find it for the last hour.

Answer (score 0):

For me that was only part of the problem. I had also installed neo4j onto my machine using **brew install** before I installed the gem.  When I was trying to start the server, it was trying to start the server from the brew installation, from inside the Cellar. I had edited the config, as described above, in the install in my project that I produced by following the neo4j install instructions. So it wasn't working.

Only when I brew uninstalled neo4j, and executed **./neo4j start_** from the bin folder, did it all work properly for me.