# Where is the "neo4j-server.properties" file on mac?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.rb

I did brew install neo4j, followed by installing the ruby gem for neo4j.

When I tried to run it, I got an error:

```
`handle_response_error!': Expected response code 200 Error for request http://localhost:7474/db/data/, 401 (Neo4j::Server::Resource::ServerException)
```

I was told on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284709/cannot-start-rails-server-with-neo4j-db-response-coed-401-instead-of-200) to modify the neo4j-server.properties file, but i could not find it in the cedars, the only files there was the bin files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the find command to find your file, if it exists on your computer:

```
find / -name "neo4j-server.properties"
```

(sudo might be needed)
This command is going to take a while.

I think brew stores everything in /usr/local/Cellar on a mac, so you can search form there:

```
find /usr/local/Cellar -name "neo4j-server.properties"
```

This doesn't answer exactly your question but I thought this may help

Comment: or faster `mdfind -name neo4j-server.properties`

Comment: why is the -name neccessary?