# How to disable Basic Authentification in Neo4j 2.2.1?

Tags: windows, authentication, neo4j, neo4jphp

Probably a stupid question, but how can I disable the basic authentification in the new Neo4j version? I looked up [How to disable Basic Auth on Neo4j 2.2.0-RC01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096616/how-to-disable-basic-auth-on-neo4j-2-2-0-rc01) but - a shame - I cannot find either the conf/neo4j-server.properties nor can I alter permamently the data/dbms/auth as mentioned in the manual. Every restart of Neo4J resets the auth-file to the previous content and delets my entries. I am using Windows 8 and in the Neo4j Community folder I cant find a way to set any properties.

As alternative I would appreciate a hint how to get the everyman_neo4j_client to send an authentification to the Neo4J DB, which would solve the problem as well and would be more secure anyway.

Maybe someone has a hint for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a gander at the [project](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/blob/0b8c6b622c4885816aca06dee9ab45bcc096d827/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Transport.php), it looks like there is a `setAuth` method in the `Transport` class that you could use.

```
/**
 * Set username and password to use with HTTP Basic Auth
 *
 * Returns this Trnasport object
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @param string $password
 * @return Transport
 */
public function setAuth($username=null, $password=null)
{
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    return $this;
}
```

You probably need to do something like this..

```
$transport = new Transport('localhost', 7474);
$transport->setAuth('neo4j', 'password')
$client = new Client( $transport );
```